# Parsing YAML comments with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to parse the comments of a yaml file using ruamel.yaml. The thing is, that I want to parse the comments in some sort of specific (I consider it logic, though) way. I have the following yaml file:

```
---
# comment for the foo variable
foo: 'foo_val'

# comment for the bar variable
bar: ['item1', 'item2']
```

And what I have been trying to do is the following:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.explicit_start = True

stream = open('my_file.yml', 'r')
loaded = yaml.load(stream) # by default is roundtrip

loaded.ca 
print(loaded)
```

what prints the following:

```
Comment(
start=[None, [CommentToken('# comment for the foo variable\n', line: 1, col: 0)]],
items={
foo: [None, None, CommentToken('\n\n# comment for the bar variable\n', line: 3, col: 0), None]})

ordereddict([('foo', 'foo_val'), ('bar', ['item1', 'item2'])])
```

As you can see, the commented map (I believe it's called so) does not keep an order. I have tried the other way, commenting below the variable definition but with the Python-style list it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the commented map without considering the first comment as that `start` object? Basically, my expected output will be each variable with the comment just on top, i.e.:

```
Comment(
    items={
    foo: [None, None, CommentToken('\n\n# comment for the foo variable\n', line: 0, col: 0), None],
    bar: [None, None, CommentToken('\n\n# comment for the bar variable\n', line: 3, col: 0), None],
  })
```

### EDIT

Ideally, I need to keep the format like in the example I presented or have a straightforward convertion from one format to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML specification requires comments to be discarded. Therefore, they are not specified in a way that gives you tight control over the node they are associated with.

ruamel does its best to map comments to where it thinks they belong to, so that the initial input can be reproduced, but it cannot generally give you the control you ask while preserving the YAML syntax.

A possible solution would be to use explicit key syntax so that you can write the comment behind the key, which would create a clear association:

```yaml
? foo # comment for the foo variable
: 'foo_val'
? bar # comment for the bar variable
: ['item1', 'item2']
```

---

**Original proposal that currently does not work as confirmed by Anthon:**

A possible solution would be to use a flow mapping, which has an explicit start and thus the comment is decidedly inside the mapping:

```yaml
{
  # comment for the foo variable
  foo: 'foo_val',

  # comment for the bar variable
  bar: ['item1', 'item2']
}
```

Note the comma after `'foo_val'` which is required by flow syntax. Indentation is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Honestly (and unfortunately for me) what you have just said makes complete sense. If the comments are discarded, the point of having control over how the are parsed is somehow pointless. I think I'll just have to handle it myself.

Comment: @ixperdomo Is this a YAML file whose content you don't control? Otherwise, my advise would be to *not* parse the comments and encode whatever information you need from them in proper YAML format.

Comment: actually this file can contain information that I won't be able to know beforehand, and it may be quite large. Anyway, thanks for the tip!

Comment: if you can add the Python code that will read the example yaml file and preserve the order and comments for each node, I'll give your answer as valid since it resolves my use case. I'm trying but apparently, the commented map is empty if I use a flow mapping.

Comment: @ixperdomo I confirmed with Anthon on the other answer that my original proposal currently does not work, I edited the question to show an alternative.

Comment: sorry if I was too fast when I told that I would mark the answer as valid. Converting the file "format" that I have to the one you first showed is pretty easy and straightforward, but converting it to the new format (that works indeed) is not trivial. To do so, I have to already parse the comments to put them in the same line as the variable so, sadly, not a valid solution for me.

Comment: actually, originally I didn't mention that the format must be kept, or the conversion should be trivial, so idk if I should add that to the question and mark your answer as valid.

Comment: @ixperdomo if everything is single-line like you show, you can get away with preprocessing via `perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/#([^\n]*)\n([^:]*):([^\n]*)/\? \2 #\1\n:\3/smg' input.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

Comments in `ruamel.yaml` are in principle associated with to the node of the key/index of the collection that is being processed, so almost never with something the parser hasn't seen yet (like you want). There are some exceptions to this (comments before any data in a file, comments between key and value), but that is the general rule. Empty lines and full line comments are treated as continuations of end-of-line comments (even if they don't exist for a certain key/index).

So although your interpretation is valid, there is currently no easy way to get to the comments like you want. Work is in progress to improve that (giving control over how the "follow-up" full line comments and emtpy lines are associated), but there is no estimate on when that will be included.

Comment: Thanks! Like the previous answer, it just makes sense. Will keep the fingers crossed to see if it comes soon enough. In the meantime, I'll handle the comments as good as I can.

Comment: There are a few question similar to yours. I'll probably go over them and update the answers/ping the OP, to let them know when things have changed.

Comment: @Anthon Could you comment on why my answer doesn't work? I assumed it does but apparently ruamel ignores comments in flow style…?

Comment: @flyx It very well possible that comments that are preserved in block style are not preserved in flow style, but your suggestion (in principle a good idea) that the curly braces would clearly associated the comment with a specific node are not followed. `ruamel.yaml` (0.17.x) tries to associate any comment/empty-line with the preceding mapping key or sequence element-index, very little special is done wrt to context (e.g. indent of a full line comment is often a dead-giveaway for humans on how to "attach" a comment, but this not (yet) used at all).